# Best way to obtain information from a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict with "multiple layers" (I don't really know how to call it) and I would like to only use few information from it. So heres the dict:

```
{'userTimestamp': 1, 
 'user': {'id': '20',
          'links': {'self': [{'href': 'https://john.com'}]},
          'mail': 'john@john.com',
          'message': 'Hello world',
          'name': 'john'}
}
```

Now I somehow want to go through the dict, get relevant information (in this case name (which is in user), message) and write the info in a new dict. What's the most efficient way to do this in python?

Comment: Is the structure defined and does not change?
Then simply for elem in your_dict should suffice

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you need but if I understood correctly, this should do?
  
  new_dict["name"] = old_dict["user"]["name"]

Comment: You dict definition is incorrect (missing ending bracket)

Comment: @ChristianSauer yes it doesn't change, but when doing a for loop I would have to iterate though all info until I'm at user, and then do a second for loop and iterate until I'm at name, to then obtain the value of name, so I need 2 for loops to obtain only 3 items from a dict, is there no other way?

Comment: You don't need loops to find a key in a dict. Just use dict[key].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something really dynamic, I'd use something like this.

```
original_dict = {
    'name': "Rahul",
    'userTimestamp': 1,
    'user': {'id': '20',
             'links': {'self': [{'href': 'https://john.com'}]},
             'mail': 'john@john.com',
             'message': 'Hello world',
             'name': 'john'}
}

def get_dict_with_relevant_fields(orig_dict, interesting_fields):
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in orig_dict.iteritems():
        if key in interesting_fields:
            new_dict[key] = value
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            new_dict.update(get_dict_with_relevant_fields(value, interesting_fields))

    return new_dict
```

So that I can call like this:

```
get_dict_with_relevant_fields(original_dict, ["id", "name"])
```

However, if you know the exact structure of your data and the position of the limited fields and where they exist in the structure. I'd always prefer this:

```
new_dict = { 
    'name': original_dict['user']['name']
    'message': original_dict['user']['message']
}
```

Even better, if I already have the utility function above, I'll use it as follows:

```
get_dict_with_relevant_fields(original_dict['user'], ['name', 'message'])
```

Of course, I am assuming there's no performance drain and the above function can easily be made much better performance wise.

Comment: in my case I know the structure will not change but thanks for the dynamic function, really nice

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
new_dict = {}
new_dict["name"] = dict["user"]["name"]
new_dict["message"] = dict["user"]["message"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of `dict` is that key lookup is the most efficient thing known to man. If you know what items you want, there is no need to "go through" the dict - just fetch them directly.

```
userdict = my_dict["user"]
```

This also applies to nested `dict`s, since at each step you'll be just getting back a pure `dict` again - which is just as efficient as the outer ones.

```
username = my_dict["user"]["name"]
```

In order to create a new `dict` from individual items of an old one, just mix item retrieval and dict creation.

```
my_new_dict = {
    'foo' : 'bar',
    'user_name' : my_dict["user"]["name"], # this will be 'john'
    'user_info' : my_dict["user"], # this will be the dict my_dict["user"]
    'user_meta' : {key: my_dict["user"][key] for key in ('name', 'mail')}, # this will be a subset of the dict my_dict["user"]
  }
```